# Geographically, where are the travis-ci jobs run?

Tags: cloud, travis-ci

Where are the travis-ci servers located?  Does travis-ci leverage AWS EC2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where are the travis-ci servers located? Does travis-ci leverage AWS EC2?

According to [this documentation](https://billing.travis-ci.com/pages/security), the servers are located in the USA and AWS EC2 is used as well.

> Your code, depending on which platform or language runtime you're
>   using, is run on virtualized servers running in:
>
> - Amazon EC2 datacenters in Ashburn, VA, USA,
> - MacStadium datacenters in Atlanta, GA, USA,
> - Google Compute Engine datacenters in Berkeley County, SC and Council Bluffs, Iowa, USA.